# Laravel - how to sum() field from relation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to optimize this code because it's causing Timeout problems.

It's getting all items from database and performing SUM() in PHP.

```
public function getInstalledCost()
{
  $items = $this->stockItems()
                              ->where('status', 'INSTALADO')
                              ->with(['shipment' => function($q){ $q->select('id', 'item_cost'); }])
                              ->select('id','shipment_id')
                              ->get();

  $cost = 0;
  foreach($items as $i){
    $cost += $i->shipment->item_cost;
  }

  return $cost;
}
```

So is there any way to get this data already SUM() from the database?

Answer (score 2):

Summing a collection in Laravel could be written shorter using the [`sum()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum)

```php
$items->sum(function ($item) {
    return count($item['item_cost']);
});
```

Just as a hint for later.

To sum a field of a relation you could probably do sth. like

```php
StockItem::whereHas('shipment', function ($q) use ($shipmentId) {
  $q->where('shipment_id', $shipmentId);
})->sum('shipments.item_price');
```

I assume you have properly set up relationships between `stockItems` and `shipments` and have a `shipments` relation on your `StockItem` model.

Comment: your first hint returns `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: your second tip needs `shipmentId` which is not my case. My StockItem class belongsTo() Shipment class

Comment: Well, for the first you need to check what is inside your $item and need to replace with the correct field. This is more or less an example.